# Dropwizard threads waiting count increases , server stops responding to all resource requests

Tags: java, rest, jetty, dropwizard

I have created a RestFul application using DropWizard framework, After serving about 20 requests the applications just stops responding. No error/exception entries are found in logging files.

Analyzing the statistics through admin control, i found
jvm.threads.waiting.count =47 which keeps on increasing with every new requests.

The application doesn't have multi-threading implemented in it, so there are no chances of application getting into wait state.

Moreover if i restart the application, it works fine.

Below is the header of one of the requests that didn't receive response

```
*152226 INFO  c.s.j.a.c.filter.LoggingFilter - 22 * Server in-bound request*
*22 > POST http://text.com/quotes*
*22 > Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5*
*22 > Host: localhost:8080*
*22 > Content-Length: 1041*
*22 > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate*
*22 > User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:34.0) *Gecko/20100101Firefox/34.0*
*22 > Trace-Id: kiki-12345*
*22 > Connection: keep-alive*
```

The request data has is not shared intentionally.

Even couldn't figure out the reason due to netstat.

I would like to know whether this is an application level issue or its due to incorrect configuration of DropWizard application?

The complete statistics from admin section is as below, Also i am interested in understanding each of these data below, and would request to share a link which explains each of these fields.

===========================

```
{
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "gauges": {
        "jvm.buffers.direct.capacity": {
            "value": 1466889
        },
        "jvm.buffers.direct.count": {
            "value": 116
        },
        "jvm.buffers.direct.used": {
            "value": 1466990
        },
        "jvm.buffers.mapped.capacity": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.buffers.mapped.count": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.buffers.mapped.used": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.gc.PS-MarkSweep.count": {
            "value": 16
        },
        "jvm.gc.PS-MarkSweep.time": {
            "value": 1354
        },
        "jvm.gc.PS-Scavenge.count": {
            "value": 21
        },
        "jvm.gc.PS-Scavenge.time": {
            "value": 153
        },
        "jvm.memory.heap.committed": {
            "value": 177733632
        },
        "jvm.memory.heap.init": {
            "value": 64984960
        },
        "jvm.memory.heap.max": {
            "value": 924844032
        },
        "jvm.memory.heap.usage": {
            "value": 0.02400968728962939
        },
        "jvm.memory.heap.used": {
            "value": 22205216
        },
        "jvm.memory.non-heap.committed": {
            "value": 50266112
        },
        "jvm.memory.non-heap.init": {
            "value": 24576000
        },
        "jvm.memory.non-heap.max": {
            "value": 136314880
        },
        "jvm.memory.non-heap.usage": {
            "value": 0.30244334294245795
        },
        "jvm.memory.non-heap.used": {
            "value": 41227528
        },
        "jvm.memory.pools.Code-Cache.usage": {
            "value": 0.03484217325846354
        },
        "jvm.memory.pools.PS-Eden-Space.usage": {
            "value": 0.027302608311733353
        },
        "jvm.memory.pools.PS-Old-Gen.usage": {
            "value": 0.018778225297105475
        },
        "jvm.memory.pools.PS-Perm-Gen.usage": {
            "value": 0.45908793007455223
        },
        "jvm.memory.pools.PS-Survivor-Space.usage": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.memory.total.committed": {
            "value": 227999744
        },
        "jvm.memory.total.init": {
            "value": 89560960
        },
        "jvm.memory.total.max": {
            "value": 1061158912
        },
        "jvm.memory.total.used": {
            "value": 63434984
        },
        "jvm.threads.blocked.count": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.threads.count": {
            "value": 78
        },
        "jvm.threads.daemon.count": {
            "value": 8
        },
        "jvm.threads.deadlocks": {
            "value": [ ]
        },
        "jvm.threads.new.count": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.threads.runnable.count": {
            "value": 23
        },
        "jvm.threads.terminated.count": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "jvm.threads.timed_waiting.count": {
            "value": 8
        },
        "jvm.threads.waiting.count": {
            "value": 47
        },
        "org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.dw.jobs": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.dw.size": {
            "value": 33
        },
        "org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.dw.utilization": {
            "value": 0.9696969696969697
        }
    },
    "counters": {
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-dispatches": {
            "count": 28
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-requests": {
            "count": 28
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-suspended": {
            "count": 0
        }
    },
    "histograms": { },
    "meters": {
        "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender.all": {
            "count": 1,
            "m15_rate": 7.747995257374595e-22,
            "m1_rate": 0.008714462773784218,
            "m5_rate": 0.000016544813111326462,
            "mean_rate": 0.00035368404453324113,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender.debug": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender.error": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender.info": {
            "count": 1,
            "m15_rate": 7.747995257374595e-22,
            "m1_rate": 0.008714462773784218,
            "m5_rate": 0.000016544813111326462,
            "mean_rate": 0.00035368403287775683,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender.trace": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender.warn": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.1xx-responses": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.2xx-responses": {
            "count": 13,
            "m15_rate": 4.94961760464336e-10,
            "m1_rate": 0.0034421634791656336,
            "m5_rate": 0.000711983613661116,
            "mean_rate": 0.004598973132381405,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.3xx-responses": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.4xx-responses": {
            "count": 3,
            "m15_rate": 2.5736064313211317e-20,
            "m1_rate": 0.00018660583536242524,
            "m5_rate": 0.0000018719139194908126,
            "mean_rate": 0.0010613014574099948,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.5xx-responses": {
            "count": 3,
            "m15_rate": 1.3432085553605237e-10,
            "m1_rate": 0.0008942559715277348,
            "m5_rate": 0.00019309079729952434,
            "mean_rate": 0.001061301432161492,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.async-dispatches": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.async-timeouts": {
            "count": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "units": "events/second"
        }
    },
    "timers": {
        "com.flightnetwork.insurance.resource.Book.book": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "com.flightnetwork.insurance.resource.Policies.doSearch": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "com.flightnetwork.insurance.resource.Quote.getQuote": {
            "count": 16,
            "max": 2.218201954,
            "mean": 0.5852605546875,
            "min": 0.36994936300000003,
            "p50": 0.468106361,
            "p75": 0.533698946,
            "p95": 2.218201954,
            "p98": 2.218201954,
            "p99": 2.218201954,
            "p999": 2.218201954,
            "stddev": 0.4414850207038381,
            "m15_rate": 6.29282616000388e-10,
            "m1_rate": 0.004336419450693371,
            "m5_rate": 0.0009050744109606403,
            "mean_rate": 0.005660256743426155,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "com.flightnetwork.insurance.resource.Refund.doRefund": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.connect-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.delete-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.dispatches": {
            "count": 19,
            "max": 2.2550000000000003,
            "mean": 0.5016315789473684,
            "min": 0.001,
            "p50": 0.46,
            "p75": 0.528,
            "p95": 2.2550000000000003,
            "p98": 2.2550000000000003,
            "p99": 2.2550000000000003,
            "p999": 2.2550000000000003,
            "stddev": 0.463604622080103,
            "m15_rate": 6.292826160261246e-10,
            "m1_rate": 0.004523025286055793,
            "m5_rate": 0.0009069463248801308,
            "mean_rate": 0.006721571867253656,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.get-requests": {
            "count": 3,
            "max": 0.05,
            "mean": 0.017666666666666667,
            "min": 0.001,
            "p50": 0.002,
            "p75": 0.05,
            "p95": 0.05,
            "p98": 0.05,
            "p99": 0.05,
            "p999": 0.05,
            "stddev": 0.028005951748393293,
            "m15_rate": 2.5736064313211317e-20,
            "m1_rate": 0.00018660583536242524,
            "m5_rate": 0.0000018719139194908126,
            "mean_rate": 0.001061300945529201,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.head-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.move-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.options-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.other-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.post-requests": {
            "count": 16,
            "max": 2.2560000000000002,
            "mean": 0.5925625,
            "min": 0.372,
            "p50": 0.47200000000000003,
            "p75": 0.5355000000000001,
            "p95": 2.2560000000000002,
            "p98": 2.2560000000000002,
            "p99": 2.2560000000000002,
            "p999": 2.2560000000000002,
            "stddev": 0.4497823130878611,
            "m15_rate": 6.29282616000388e-10,
            "m1_rate": 0.004336419450693371,
            "m5_rate": 0.0009050744109606403,
            "mean_rate": 0.005660270596836139,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.put-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.requests": {
            "count": 38,
            "max": 2.2560000000000002,
            "mean": 0.5017105263157895,
            "min": 0.001,
            "p50": 0.46,
            "p75": 0.528,
            "p95": 2.25505,
            "p98": 2.2560000000000002,
            "p99": 2.2560000000000002,
            "p999": 2.2560000000000002,
            "stddev": 0.4573666639487485,
            "m15_rate": 1.2585652320522491e-9,
            "m1_rate": 0.009046050572111585,
            "m5_rate": 0.0018138926497602615,
            "mean_rate": 0.013443138586906005,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.trace-requests": {
            "count": 0,
            "max": 0,
            "mean": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "p50": 0,
            "p75": 0,
            "p95": 0,
            "p98": 0,
            "p99": 0,
            "p999": 0,
            "stddev": 0,
            "m15_rate": 0,
            "m1_rate": 0,
            "m5_rate": 0,
            "mean_rate": 0,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        },
        "org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory.80.connections": {
            "count": 37,
            "max": 116.233045153,
            "mean": 18.87723851451351,
            "min": 0.078290967,
            "p50": 0.570973454,
            "p75": 33.0824538595,
            "p95": 87.55158713740005,
            "p98": 116.233045153,
            "p99": 116.233045153,
            "p999": 116.233045153,
            "stddev": 32.65398107624642,
            "m15_rate": 0.006718640480106826,
            "m1_rate": 0.018519557829824465,
            "m5_rate": 0.024412722112445752,
            "mean_rate": 0.013086852776973062,
            "duration_units": "seconds",
            "rate_units": "calls/second"
        }
    }

}
```

========================

Comment: Can you see those 20 requests being successfully served in the logs? Just to rule out that threads being stuck. It could be a third party library doing that after all..

Comment: Yes, the 20 requests are served successfully, We later on observed it has to do with db connection pool size, increasing it to 50 served 50 requests successfully and then the server stopped responding as earlier.

Comment: It's a bit difficult without seeing the code really. Maybe it's your database connections? Maybe you aren't closing them after you're done? Are you using jdbc? jdbi? hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 potential causes of this issue:

#### 1) Not closing your response properly

More info from [this blog post](http://phillbarber.blogspot.ca/2014/02/lessons-learned-from-connection-leak-in.html).

You can use `netstat -a  | grep CLOSE_WAIT | wc -l` to get the thread count.

You can get a thread dump by running:

`jps`
then seeing what your app's process id is, and passing it to this command:
To obtain a thread dump using jstack, run the following command:

`jstack <pid>`

Run the same command every once in awhile and append to the same file. You need more than one dump, spaced apart in time to detect long running threads

`jstack <pid> >> threaddumps.log`

Then use a [thread dump analyzer](https://github.com/irockel/tda) to compare your first dump and 2nd dump, to see what threads are running long by selecting multiple dumps, right clicking and choose "Find long running threads"

You probably need to make sure you're closing a ClientResponse, as is being done here:

```
public boolean isSessionActive(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
   ClientResponse response = null;
   try{
      response = jerseyClient
         .resource(url)
         .type(APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
         .header("Cookie", httpRequest.getHeader("Cookie"))
         .get(ClientResponse.class);
      return response.getStatus() == SC_OK;
   }
   finally {
      if (response != null){
         // #############################################
         // This next line is the fix you're looking for!
         // #############################################
         response.close();
      }
   }
}
```

#### 2) Not having enough concurrent threads allocated

MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager with it's default configuration only allows 2 concurrent requests per host! So if you're hitting the same server constantly with different request data, you're possibly being limited to 2 active requests at a time. And if it happens that those 2 requests take a long time to complete, then you've got no connections available, and will get WAITs.

How can this happen? For us, we were using ApacheHttpClient with DropWizard 0.6.2, which behind the scenes was creating an MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager with a default configuration - and that [default configuration](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.html#setMaxConnectionsPerHost(int)) only allowed 2 concurrent http connections at a time)

We thought we were passing in config to bump this # up, but in reality it wasn't being used, and our server was only processing 2 requests at a time ;-)

So check the following to ensure they're values you expect!

```
  MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = ...;
  connectionManager.getParams().getDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost();
  connectionManager.getParams().getMaxTotalConnections();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are closing responses if you are using Jersey Client to call other services - underlying http connection pools might be empty.

To find out where the threads are waiting you need to generate a thread dump (use jvisualvm, jstack or kill -3). Once you know where the threads are waiting the solution should be obvious.

Also - which version of dropwizard are you using?

Comment: We are using dropwizard 0.7.0. Thanks for the reply, we will analyze on the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was related to DB connections left open.
Basically we're using JPA and there are some cases where wo do 
`EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();`
and forgot to `em.close`

Not catching rollbacks might also be related.

Answer (score 0):

This means active requests are stuck on some resource, it could be anything, a memory leak, a deadlock, etc.

Rather then going and checking every client (the list can be long), take a thread dump using jstack, JMC, or looking using jconsole.

you would see threads waiting with the point at which they are blocked. In my case it was

```
"dw-4104 - POST /something" #4104 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4f3c074000 nid=0x306c waiting on condition [0x00007f4db00ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000041cb8f780> (a jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:285)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.getResponseContext(ResponseWriter.java:299)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.callSendError(ResponseWriter.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.commit(ResponseWriter.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:413)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:784)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:239)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:674)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

the above is waiting on response writing to client. Apparantly we were reusing response object, which got consumed in the first respone, subsequent requests were blocked on response.